# Facing issue while scraping instagram api

Tags: web-scraping, instagram, screen-scraping, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have a scheduled job that runs every day to fetch the list of following and followers of my profile. I append the following at the end of URL (?__a=1) to fetch data.
Since yesterday, I am getting this error in logs:

`for (;;);{"__ar":1,"error":1357004,"errorSummary":"Sorry, something went wrong","errorDescription":"Please try closing and re-opening your browser window.","payload":null,"hsrp":{"hblp":{"consistency":{"rev":1005620371}}},"lid":"7104658052927816905"}`

Did Instagram change its API configuration since June 1? Why am I getting this response and what should I do to fix this?

Comment: any answer to this?